# Android Studio's emulator doesnt start on mac

Tags: android, emulation, device

When I try to run an app, it shows the black phone and stays on "waiting for device to come online". 
Now I tried to launch the emulator by clicking on the start button on the AVD Manager. It stays like this (black) for minutes and doesn't start.
I have seen a lot of people with this problem but couldn't find a working solution.

**Emulator:**

[image: Emulator]

[image: Logcat]

Comment: Please post the logcat log.

Comment: @BhalchandraSW done. it just says "waiting for target device to come online"

Comment: Follow steps for [displaying and running App in the logcat Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html#running) and post the logcat output.

Comment: @BhalchandraSW i got a lot of stuff. added the error it showed. thanks.